# Pointer issue sending it as a constant

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I'm working again with c++ since a while and I have a doubt sending pointers as parameters in a function.

I wanted to send an object pointer to a function but with a const state, to know that the object pointed by the pointer was not going to be modified any time. So I did this:

```
int hi(const SomeObject* so)
{
    so->SayHi();
}

SomeObject* so = new SomeObject();
hi(so);
```

But it didn't work. It says incompatible types...

Also, would it be different if I add the const to the function too? Like:

```
int hi(const SomeObject* so) const;
```

Can anyone explain me this doubt? Thanks

Comment: How are you calling it? What are you passing? What's the full error?

Comment: "it says compatible types"? That doesn't sound like a compiler error to me. Maybe you should show us your *actual* code, and the *actual* error you're getting. :)

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the complete error, and also show _how_ you are calling it, and how you declare the variable you use in the call.

Comment: What is the code for the class `SomeObject`? Is the method `SayHi` const?

Comment: As for adding `const` to the function, you can't do that. Only member function can be constant, telling the compiler that they will not modify the object the method is in.

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: Are there templates involved?

Comment: I think there is no error here as compiler may implicitly convert the raw pointer to const pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int hi(const SomeObject* so)
```

You have declared `SomeObject` to be constant. This would cause a compiler error if sayHi is not declared const as well.

```
class SomeObject {
  void sayHi(void) const;
}
```

If your intention was to make the pointer constant (not the object it points to) it should look like this:

```
int hi(SomeObject* const so)
```

[Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/c-constant-pointers/) you can read about pointers and constant pointers